# Handling a Variable Number of `useState` in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

The current React app that uses `useState` and `useEffect` shown below takes an object `params` from the user and uses it to query an API server to obtain the results `chartData` and `tableData` which are then displayed using the `Chart` and `Table` components. This works fine.

However, the app must now be modified to display **multiple** (and a **variable** number of) search results at the same time on both the `Chart` and `Table` components. There will always be a single `Chart` and a single `Table` component irregardless of the number of search `params`.

**Question:** This is where I am stuck! How do we maintain seperate `useState` and `useEffect`, one for each set of search `params` so that when only one of the search `params` is changed, not all the searches will need to be done, since these `params` remained unchanged.

Additionally, all the `chartData` from all the different search `params` will be combined together and passed into the `Chart` component, similarly for the `TableData` and its `Table` component.

**Current App**

```js
export function Main() {
    const [ params, setParams ] = useState({name: 'foo'});
    const [ chartData, setChartData ] = useState([]);
    const [ tableData, setTableData ] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost/chart', {params: params})
            .then(response => {
                setChartData(response.data)
            })

        axios
            .get('http://localhost/table', {params: params})
            .then(response => {
                setTableData(response.data)
            })
    }, [params])

    return (
        <div>
            <Chart data={chartData} />
            <Table data={tabletData} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

**Edit:** I am thinking of the following data structure, but can not figure out how to create the React hooks and its dependency arrays...

```js
searches = [
    {
        name: 'foo',
        params: {...},
        chartData: [{}, {}, ...],
        tableData: [{}, {}, ...],
    },
    {
        name: 'bar',
        params: {...},
        chartData: [{...}, ...],
        tableData: [{...}, ...],
    },
    ...
]
```

and `Chart` component will be accepting an array using its `data` parameter which will look similar to

```js
[
    {
        name: 'foo',
        data: [{...}, ...],
    },
    {
        name: 'bar',
        data: [{...}, ...],
    },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ES2015 or later, you can utilise computed property names.

```
searches = {
    [name]:{
        params: {...},
        chartData: [{}, {}, ...],
        tableData: [{}, {}, ...],
    }
}
```

Thank you could access it as `searches.foo` or `searches.bar`. Rather than always filtering based in the name.